# Howland current source for negative currents

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, circuit-analysis, current, current-source

I am currently in the process of utilizing the design of Howland in order to derive a source that is able to provide an \$I_{out}\$ between \$0A\$ and \$30A\$ at the output load \$R_L\$.
[image]

As you can see from the figure, the op-amp is configured similar to a differential amplifier. The output current can be calculated using the equation \$I_{out} = \frac{k \cdot V_{IN}}{R_s}\$ whereby \$k\$ is given as \$k = \frac{R_2}{R_1}\$. The output of the op-amp drives the N-MOSFET and by varying the input voltage \$V_{IN}\$ at the non-inverting input, the desired amplitude of the current can be set. The voltage \$V_{IN}\$ comes from a DAC.

I am able to achieve the desired currents however I am now asking myself if it is possible to use this kind of circuit in order to achieve currents in the interval between \$0A\$ and \$-30A\$. I am not sure if this is simply a task of using a P-MOSFET and connecting it's drain with ground and applying a negative voltage of \$-18V\$ at the load. I tried simulating this kind of situation however I was not able to achieve the desired result. Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I came up with a possible circuit for my problem: [image]
I am now using a P-MOSFET where the drain is connected to the negative supply rail which I increased for now to \$-50V\$. The same also applies to the positive supply rail. Additionally, I also changed the op-amp used to drive the MOSFET and removed the op-amp in the positive feedback path.

[image]
As you can see from the DC-sweep, I am now able to control the current through the load by applying a voltage between \$0V\$ and \$-3.3V\$. The formula for the output current still applies, however now the sign is inverted. As I intend to control the output current with a DAC, I would have to use an inverting amplifier in order to convert the voltage of the DAC to a negative one. As suggested by Jens, I included a Zener-Diode between the gate and the source. Are there any additional improvements for this circuit possible?

Comment: The difference would be that the DAC still provides positive voltages, but all other voltages would be below GND. I think your suggested solution is possible with that in mind. If the load is connected to +18V things are different.

Comment: 30 A in 1 Ohm -> power supply > min 40 V ... and op-amp are high voltage also ...

Comment: Not really related to the OP but, why, oh why did you use the ohmygodawful autogenerated symbols for subcircuits when you already have the opamp right there in the database?! Just press `F2` and type `4625`, it will take you straight to it, if you can't find it in `[Opamps]`. Also, you already used `1k` and `2.5k` as values for resistors, why stop there and not use `5m` for `R_s`? It would be much more readable and less error-prone when reading all the zeroes. BTW, `R` is not a unit so it will be silently discarded, just like `V` in `3.3V`. It won't hurt, just a reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a similar idea used in a current sink circuit. An N channel MOSFET has some advantages here, because the OpAmp feedback loop does not include the load voltage. At supply voltages above 20V the gate must be protected using a Z diode between gate and source.

There are instrumentation OpAmps which include the 4 resistors in a fixed gain of 20 configuration available.

I used a sawtooth generator in the simulation representing the DAC dynamic range.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0sYbc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Well, why not join both into a bidirectional one?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVlyXP.png)</sup>

There will be a small glitch when U_DAC crosses zero because the OpAmp must jump from +U(gs)th to -U(gs)th of the other FET. This can be optimized.

Comment: I am wondering if this circuit is able to provide a negative voltage \$U_{LOAD}\$, so a negative output current \$I_{out}\$ is achieved. I thought that for this kind of situation a P-MOSFET is required? If you have a look at my edit, I came up with a possible solution that utilizes a P-MOSFET.

Comment: @Nick: Yes, it will. Look at the "upside down" supply at the bottom. My assumptions were: Still having a positive input voltage from a DAC and load grounded. Your load connection is different, this was not clear to me.

Comment: I think I understand your circuit now. Thank you very much. Just one more question: in the solution from my edit the load is also grounded or am I confusing something right now, so the load connections should be the same for both circuits (yours and mine)?

Comment: @Nick: Yes, the load configuration is the same, just the DAC output is neagative in yours, the P-FET ends at 25A and the OpAmp is very expensive :;  You need only +5V in your circuit, this OpAmp needs 3V distance to the rails, 50V is an overkill. The OpAmp driving the Z diode in series with just 80 Ohm at 50V is critical.

Comment: Ok thank you I will have a closer look at your circuit. Could you maybe elaborate a little bit on what you mean by critical.

Comment: @Nick: If there is a non zero voltage at V3 and you don't have a load the OpAmp output will saturate close to V2 (-50V). The Z diode voltage subtracted, the difference of around 30V are across R6. This is nominal 375mA and OpAmp and Z diode are overloaded.

Comment: Why is the resistor \$R_3\$ required in the bidirectional current source? I know that in this configuration it is needed so that the gate and source pins of the MOSFETs are at different potentials. However, isn't it also possible to completely leave out the connection between \$R_2\$ and the source pins of the MOSFETs?

Comment: @Nick: Yes, R3 is not needed. It defines gate charges at power on/off and it is a feedback path when M1 and M2 are off and no load is connected.

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to achieve the desired currents however I am now asking myself if it is possible to use this kind of circuit in order to achieve currents in the interval between 0A and −30A.

Yes. You can.

Here is a simulation with your value (MOSFET -> N for first try). EE&O.
But **Power supplies should be higher** ... on a 1 Ohm load.

DC Dynamic analysis made with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip).
Beware for the dissipated power by the MOSFET ... Not all devices checked.
Must check also AC analysis ... and TRANsient analysis for stability.

[image]

Transient Analysis

[image]

> I am not sure if this is simply a task of using a P-MOSFET and connecting it's drain with ground and applying a negative voltage of −18V at the load.

Possible also, as in "push-pull" operation. Driver gate adapted. Will try later.
However, with some conditions, if you want the 2 in the same "box".
NB: 30 A in 1 Ohm need supply voltage greater the |40 V|, and op-amp too, in this configuration.

[image]

Comment: For such high levels of current, you don't need the opamp follower X1 -- connect R3 directly to Vo. 

Of course this circuit requires very good matching of the four resistors.

Comment: The question, as I understand, was about building a similar circuit as current sink using a P-FET analog to the working current source

Comment: Right for the "follower". Op-amps used is a dual device ... :-) ... Ok, but I don't like really P-FET ... And no models known. Will try it after, but driving gate seems not "good" in OP. As power supply voltages, too low.